# Removing trailing slashes at an nginx subdirectory

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I have a Symfony application at `mysite.com` and a WordPress application at `mysite.com/blog`:

```
server {
    server_name mysite.com;
    root /var/www/mysite/symfony/web;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        internal;
    }

    location /blog {
        root /var/www/mysite/wordpress;
        rewrite ^/blog/(.+)$ /$1 break;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php$is_args$args;

        location ~ \.php {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(?:\/blog\/)(.+\.php)(.*);
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.com-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.com-error.log;
}
```

When I access my blog route (`mysite.com/blog`), nginx 301 redirects to add a trailing slash (`mysite.com/blog/`). Is there any way I can avoid this redirect? I've noticed this doesn't happen with Symfony - `mysite.com/admin` works fine.

I've tried adding `rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1;`, but this just results in a redirect loop.

Answer (score 0):

The trailing slash is added by WordPress. You can disable it by going to your WordPress `Settings -> Permalinks`, choose custom structure and remove the trailing slash.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I believe this setting only refers to posts. I confirmed this by placing a `die;` at the top of WordPress' index.php - I still get redirected.

Comment: I see. Maybe you should have a look at https://tommcfarlin.com/trailing-slash-in-wordpress/